# Error in function max() for 3 number in python

Tags: python, function, max

I'm beginner in python but I don't understand a thing.
This is the Code:

```
a = input("Insert first number ")
b = input("Insert second number ")
c = input("Insert third number ")
print("Max number is", max(a, b, c))
```

For example, I write at prompt:

```
Insert first number 12
Insert second number 34
Insert third number 100
Max number is 34
```

I don't understand! Please answer me!

Answer (score 1):

Input returns string and strings are compared lexicographically. You should cast all input results to int, to get numbers.